# Error when copying a csv file to a table using SQL Shell (psql)

Tags: postgresql

I have a file test.csv with two lines:

```
"smth", "1", "2", "3"
"smth more", "4", "5", "6"
```

I'm trying to copy it to a table with sql shell:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT, col4 TEXT);
COPY test_table FROM 'E:\\PostgreSQL13\\scripts\\test.csv';
```

And get the following error:

```
 wrong syntax for type integer: """"smth"", ""1"", ""2"", ""3""""
```

What could be the problem here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Tell [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) you are inputing a `csv`, so it will use the default comma separator and recognize the double quotes. (`text` format is the default)

```sql
COPY test_table FROM 'E:\\PostgreSQL13\\scripts\\test.csv' (FORMAT 'csv')
```